# measuring the accuracy of a model and the importance of a feature in SVM

Tags: machine-learning, regression, libsvm

I'm starting to use `LIBSVM` for regression analysis.  My world has about 20 features and thousands to millions of training samples.

I'm curious about two things:

1. Is there a metric that indicates the accuracy or confidence of the model, perhaps in the .model file or elsewhere?
2. How can I determine whether or not a feature is significant?  E.g., if I'm trying to predict body weight as a function of height, shoulder width, gender and hair color, I might discover that hair color is not a significant feature in predicting weight.  Is that reflected in the .model file, or is there some way to find out?

Answer (score 2):

libSVM calculates *p*-values for test points based upon the certainty of the classifier (i.e., how far is the test point from the decision boundary and how wide are the margins).

I think you should consider the determination of feature importance a separate problem from training your SVMs.  There are **tons** of approaches for "feature selection" (just open any text book) but one easy to understand, straightforward approach would be a simple cross-validation as follows:

1. Divide your dataset into **k** folds (e.g., **k** = 10 is common)
2. For each of the **k** folds:

   1. Separate your data into train/test sets (the current fold is the test set, the rest are the training set)
   2. Train your SVM classifier using only **n**-1 of your **n** features
   3. Measure the prediction performance
3. Average the performance of your **n**-1 feature classifier for all **k** test folds
4. Repeat 1-3 for all remaining features

You could also do the reverse where you test each of the **n** features separately but you will likely miss out on important second and higher order interactions between the features.

In general, however, SVMs are good at ignoring irrelevant features.

You may also want to try and visualize your data using Principal Components Analysis to get a feel for how the data is distributed.

Comment: good stuff, but one clarification -- you said: "libSVM calculates p-values for test points based upon the certainty of the classifier" -- does it make a difference that I'm doing regression and not classification?

Comment: I've never used libsvm for regression so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The ***F-score*** is a metric commonly used for *features selection* in Machine Learning.

Since version 3.0, LIBSVM library includes a directory called *tools*. In that directory is a python script called *fselect.py*, which calculates F-score. To use it, just execute from the command line and pass in the file comprised of training data (and optionally a testing data file).

```
python fselect.py data_training data_testing
```

The output is comprised of an ***fscore*** for each of the features in your data set which corresponds to the importance of that feature to the model result (regression score).

Comment: that looks like it will do the trick (for part II of my question).  FWIW, fselect.py is included int the tools directory in libsvm-3.1 (from www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/), but you can download it separately from www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/fselect/fselect.py

Comment: @fearless_fool--I intended my Answer to address *both* parts of your Q--i.e., the _F-statistic_ (or F-score) is my Answer to part I.

Comment: I don't see how fselect can work for regression testing: it calls tools/grid.py rather than gridregression.py, so it cannot choose good params for training.  Am I missing something?

Comment: ... and reading up on the definition of f-score (2 * p * r) / (p + r), it appears that f-score refers specifically to classification problems, not regression.  Again, there may be a relationship between classification and regression that I don't understand yet.